# Unable to connect to VM Linux through Putty on my Windows desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, putty

**Introduction**

Hello, I'm extreme beginner here. I am trying to connect my Putty with VM linux. This is how I started:

1. Install Ubuntu 18 with OpenSSH.
2. Enable NAT and Bridge network (my Wifi driver) with my system's MAC address.
3. Since it could not fetch my IP (despite disabling firewall), i had to assign a static IP.

When I tried to connected with Putty , it says Connection time out. I tried the following solutions so far.

**Solutions**

1. Just in case if i forgot to check mark the install openssh installation. I used `sudo apt-get install openssh-server -y` but i found it has the error of **Temporary failure resolving archive.ubuntu.com**. I searched youtube for this error and found out I need to use this `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf ((GREATHER THAN)) /dev/null` or for a permanent solution `sudo nano etc/resolv.config/` and change nameserver to `8.8.8.8` and finally `sudo nano etc/apt/sources.list` and I found that all of them had the right credentials i.e. /ubuntu bionic-security , /ubuntu bionic backports , /ubuntu bionic updates etc.

Can anyone tell where to look for now as I'm quite frustrated.

Edit 1: Status of `sudo service ssh status`

[image]

Edit 2:

My machine IP address: 192.168.56.1
My VM IP address: 192.168.56.10

When I wrote on my VM's linux terminal `ssh 192.168.56.1` it says

*connect to host 192.168.56.1 port 22: No route to host*

and when I wrote `ssh -v 192.168.56.1` it says the same thing.

Comment: Welcome to the board. I assume that you are using Windows, since you are using Putty? In any case: which VM software are you using? Is it Oracle, VMWare or something else?

Comment: Is the ssh server running on Ubuntu? What is the output of `sudo service ssh status` and sudo service sshd status`?

Comment: Thanks @terdon , I've just added the screen shot for the command it says active and the VM software is from Oracle.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222) if you can avoid it (you might not be able to avoid it from a VM, I know). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: Also, please add the output of `sudo service sshd status` as requested as well. Next, if that shows active too, we need to see: i) the _exact_ command you use to connect (are you using a server name? an IP address?) and ii) the same command, but with `-v`, so if you were doing `ssh 1.2.3.4`, now do `ssh -v 1.2.3.4`.

Comment: @terdon , thank you so much sir. The picture you see above is when I typed `sudo service sshd status`. As for connecting VM with my host machine, I wrote VM's static IP (192.168.56.10) address on Putty. I did not use any command in my VM linux terminal as you suggested like `ssh 1.2.3.4`. 

**I tried what you said**
My machine IP address: 192.168.56.1
My VM IP address: 192.168.56.10

When I wrote on my VM's linux terminal `ssh 192.168.56.1` it says __connect to host 192.168.56.1 port 22: No route to hose__ and when I wrote `ssh -v 192.168.56.1`  it says the same thing.

Comment: Please ***edit*** your question and include all details there because comments are hard to read and can be deleted without warning. However, this sounds like it is a question of configuring putty correctly. You might want to delete your question here and ask instead on [su] where people with both Windows and Linux experience can be found.